# InOut exchange pattern has Out always null

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel

I am using composed request message for http services.

```
Order finalOrder = (Order) producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:processRequests", myOrder);
```

I am calling route with above code.and i know requestBody() method uses InOut pattern.But when i am trying to check whether final exchange has out message it is giving false.

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        /*onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(true);*/

        from("direct:processRequests")
                .split(body().method("getItems"), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
                .parallelProcessing()
                .to("direct:processRequest")
                .end()
       .end();


        from("direct:processRequest")
        .choice()   
        .when(body().method("getHttpDetails").method("getCallType").isEqualTo("POST"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, body().method("getHttpDetails").method("getCallType"))
            .setProperty("sendTo",body().method("getEndPointUri"))
            .setBody(body().method("getPayload"))
           .toD("${exchangeProperty.sendTo}")
}
}
```

I was able to get response body in In message instead of Out.I am proccesing exchanges in aggreator class.

```
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        System.out.println("hasout "+newExchange.hasOut());
       // remaining code
```

newExchange.hasOut() is always false.Message is propagating in In Messsage .Can any one explain how to propagate final response message in Out Message.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: Thanks for responding.But i don't get it how to make the routes mentioned above to use InOut pattern. I want to make final response available in Out message.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Flow of an exchange through a route section](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html#UsinggetInorgetOutmethodsonExchange-Flowofanexchangethrougharoute) in the Camel Exchange documentation:

> The out message from each step is used as the in message for the next
>   step

This may be why you are experiencing the issue you are.  In my experience, the response is almost never in the out message, and I just copy it to the out message as follows (if needed):

```
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.setOut(exchange.getIn());
    }
})
```

This is usually not necessary, however.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I already wondered where my response went...

Comment: Hey glad to help! Yes this is one of those Camel things that is not very intuitive at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the ExchangePattern to inOut right before you toD(..) call like so:

```
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
.toD("${exchangeProperty.sendTo}")
```

Also, have you tried using [recipientList](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html)? I have only used this to do what you're trying to do since I am running an older version of Camel.  To do so, you would replace your toD(..) with something like:

```
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
recipientList(simple("${exchangeProperty.sendTo}"))
```

Let me know if either of these approaches work.